# What code will help me check a string for at least 2 numericals characters?

Tags: vb.net

Basically, I am trying to create a random password generator using VB. However I am stumped at one certain place. I do not know how to check the string to see if at least 2 numerical characters have been inserted. I thought maybe a contain would help but I can only check for one character. Can anyone help me? The code at the moment is placed below:

```
        Dim sChars As String="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmMNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ1234567890"
        Dim sPassword As String = ""
        Dim iLength As Integer
        Do Until iLength >= 10 And sPassword.Contains(???)
        Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following scenario

```
    Dim sChars As String = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmMNBV1CXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ"
    Dim output As String = New String((From c As Char In sChars Select c Where Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
    If output.Length >= 2 Then
        MsgBox("success")
    Else
        MsgBox("Doesn't meet the requirement") ' for this input this message will displayed
    End If
```

suppose the input will be

`Dim sChars As String="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmMNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ1234567890"`  then it will display `Success`

Comment: In my opinion this answer is better suited to the OP's requirement than the actual accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for matching the regex expressions:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d{2}")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match("Dot 77 Perls")
    If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
    End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

This will match for two numerical occurrences in the string and return the result. You can use the regex match in your web/console application and not execute the entire module

Comment: with all respect can i ask one thing? in this question it is clearly asked that  `how to check the string to see if at least 2 numerical characters have been inserted`. does this answer meet this requirement? consider this input `qwertyuiopasdfghjklzx1cvbnmMNBVCXZLKJHGFDSA1POIU2YTREWQ` it contains `three` numeric values `1,1,2` but this snippet will not give the exact result as expected. it will check only for `Two consecutive numbers`. but in the question he is asking for at least `2` numerals. hence this answer is partially wrong. so i put down vote

Comment: @LittleMaster yes it wasn't specifically what I was asking. However, I adapted it to meet my needs. They are all very good answers but I has some experience in Regex before and therefore chose this as the answer.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question fully as the OP specified `two numerical values`, yet you assume that they are together (which they are not). In my opinion `user4365195`'s answer is far better than this accepted answer as it fully meets the OP's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A little faster version than the regex approach:

```
    Dim password As String = "somePasswordToTest24hehe6"
    Dim numberCounter As Integer
    Dim counterLimit As Integer = 2
    Dim hasValidCountOfNumbers As Boolean
    For Each ch As Char In password
        If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
           numberCounter += 1
        End If
        If numberCounter >= counterLimit Then
           hasValidCountOfNumbers = True
           Exit For
        End If
   Next

   If hasValidCountOfNumbers Then
                'do probably nothing
   Else
                'notify that password validation failed
   End If
```

Comment: Yes ! @fabigler answer is the same answer that I wanted to post without regex .. ! use it ! :)